# What is Delphi "External exception C0FB007F"?

Tags: delphi

I get an "External exception C0FB007F" when I run the program outside IDE/debugger.
Where can I find the description for this message?

The only reference I can find about it is [here](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2009/09/once-upon-a-delayed-jvcl-time/) but I don't use Jedi.

Comment: How about using a debugger to find out where it is thrown? Not sure if the delphi integrated one can do that, or if you need another debugger such as ollydbg.

Comment: Can you work out which line of code provokes the exception?

Comment: @CodeInChaos If olly can do it, so can the integrated debugger

Comment: I found many different hits in Google - all for .exe's written in Delphi.  For example:  http://openiv.com/?p=486.  Please make sure you've enabled all exceptions in your debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an exception generated by the Delphi code, but by some external code.

It may be a third party library or component (e.g. COM object or external .dll) which raise this exception. As Remko states, it is certainly a third-party library which is not able to resolve one of its dependencies.

Use [an exception logging system](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/04/14/Enhanced-logging-in-SynCommons) to retrieve when it happens.

It may be related to [this know JCL issue](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2009/09/once-upon-a-delayed-jvcl-time/) (if you use this library).

Answer (score 4):

There are several definitions in the SDK headers for HRESULT 0xC0FB007F:

- UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP                                   bugcodes.h
- NMERR_REMOTE_VERSION_OUTOFSYNC                                netmon.h
- SQL_127_severity_15                                           sql_err
- ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND                                          winerror.h

Hard to tell without knowing the context, but ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND seems most likely and it means that you are linking to an export in a dll that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Altar Every Delphi app uses DLLs. Another link with info [here](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2009/08/29/version-checking-for-delphi/).

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I will rephrase: Except the DLL that Delphi applications use normally (GDI32, Kernel, etc) and which cannot be missing from a system, I don't use other DLLs.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a delphi thing.  We normally get external exception when running a program on a network and it or one of its dlls gets deleted or looses the connection to the network and the application throws up an external exception.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I tried to call a DLL written in Visual C++ from an executable written in (previously Borland) C++ Builder.
Builder did not know how to read a COFF DLL. I fixed it by creating a .lib file from the DLL with implib (comes with Builder/Delphi), and linking to that .lib file (not the one created by VC++).
The Borland lib file can then read the Microsoft DLL.